# IllegalStateMonitor exception on Thread Execution

Tags: java, multithreading, mutex, illegalstateexception

I don't understand why we get an IllegalMonitorState exception here. If the thread1 has synchronized on the boolean flag then how is thread2 able to change it. shouldn't it block on thread1? this code gives IllegalMonitorState exception because the wait is called after thread2 changes the value of the flag. i'm having trouble understanding why thread2 did not get blocked here.

class IncorrectSynchronization {

```
Boolean flag = new Boolean(true);

public void example() throws InterruptedException {

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            synchronized (flag) {
                try {
                    while (flag) {
                        System.out.println("First thread about to sleep");
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                        System.out.println("Woke up and about to invoke wait()");
                        flag.wait();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {

                }
            }
        }
    });

    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            flag = false;
            System.out.println("Boolean assignment done.");
        }
    });

    t1.start();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    t2.start();
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

}

I'm having trouble understanding at which point did thread 1 relinquish lock on flag

Comment: Why do you think that thread 2 *should* be blocked? Does it use synchronization anywhere?

Comment: The boolean value is immutable. When you change the value you swap in a different object, now you're calling wait on something you didn't synchronize on.